# Solving for $x=0.14$ from $0.32-0.32x=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve for $x$ on the problem: $$0.32-0.32x=2x$$ I am doing this with the example problem and it shows that the answer is $x=0.14$, but I am not sure how they obtained this answer.

Comment: Do you know how to factorise? E.g. $2x+3x=(2+3)x$?

Comment: @windy401: $x = \dfrac{0.32}{2.32}$. I assume you know how to isolate $x$. They also rounded to two places.

Comment: Thanks, both of you.

@Com: thanks for the edit, yea I do know that, just wasn't seeing it, haven't even had to do it set up like that before. I'm been self teaching myself everything past basic math so, lot of holes.

Comment: Fair enough, we all have many holes in our understanding :). Good on you for trying to fill them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$0.32-0.32x=2x$$
You want to understand how factorising works really, and first you need to add $.32x$ to both sides:

$$0.32-0.32x \color{green}{+0.32x}=2x\color{green}{+0.32x}$$
Now simplify:
$$0.32=2x+0.32x$$
And factorising is recognizing the same term occurring and simplifying it:
$$0.32=(2+0.32)x=2.32x$$
Now divide
$$\frac{0.32}{2.32}=x$$

Answer (score 2):

It is simply not true.  Why do you think it is?  $$0.32-0.32x=2x\\0.32=2.32x\\x=\frac {0.32}{2.32}\approx 0.13793$$
If the constants are measured numbers, but the $2$ is exact, you could round to two places and get $0.14$, but this is a math site and we tend to think numbers are exact.

Comment: True, that is a good point. Technically it's part of a long chem problem, sig figs and all, so in the end it'll work out the same, but still good to note!